# Select using "this" keyword using document.on(..) - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nested

My html code ( which is fetched from a json file after the page is loaded ):

```
<div class="fooditem">
       <select class="quan">
               <option value="0">0</option>
       </select>
 </div>
```

My javascript/jquery code :

```
$(document).on("click", ".fooditem", function() {
    $(this).find('.quan').click();
});
```

I want to to click the select option tag when i click the div.
I found that the `this` keyword, here, is representing the `document` not the particular class.
So how should I go about doing it?
Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3faebrtu/)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  What version of jQuery?  Perhaps create a JSFiddle.

Comment: Wait, it shouldn't be.... `this` should be the element...

Comment: It is NOT a good idea to trigger an infinite loop of clicks. Does your `.quan` stop event propagation?

Comment: 3 comments: 1) Your code causes a recursive call because you trigger click on a descendant from inside a click handler. 2) You cannot get a select to "open" by sending it a click event. 3) You need to clarify your overall aim. e.g. do you just need to give the select focus after clicking the surrounding div?

Comment: Aim is to "open" the select by clicking in the div.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

**First Problem:**

You are getting an infinite loop by listening to `click` but then generating a `click` on a descendant element...

The only solution to that is:

- Move the child element outside of the element catching the click.

*Note: You cannot block the click handler of the select or it will stop working.*

As an alternative you can however do one of the following:

- Set focus on the `select` element
- Change the value of the `select` element
- Generate a `change` event on the `select` element (as if the element was chosen)

**but you cannot get the select to simply pop open and select the item.**

Examples below:

1) Set focus

```
$(document).on("click", ".fooditem", function(e) {
    $(this).find('.quan').focus();
});
```

2) Change the selected value

```
$(document).on("click", ".fooditem", function(e) {
    $(this).find('.quan').val(0); // or whatever value
});
```

3) Generate a change event on the select element

```
$(document).on("click", ".fooditem", function(e) {
    $(this).find('.quan').trigger('change');
});
```

note: This can be done with or without a prior value change.

Note: You have said in comment "i just want the drop down to open and select the value when i click on div", but this will not happen. A click event will not trigger opening of a select. See this example which has the recursion avoided (the elements are not nested): jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zgub3838/7

Answer (score -1):

You are binding your onclick event to the document. Try changing your jQuery snippet to this:

```
$(".fooditem").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.quan').click();
});
```

Comment: That was a delegated event handler and was valid. The e.preventdefault() is the key (but only if present in a handler for `".quan"`.

Comment: -1: This code still has the recursion error (which is the actual problem): http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zgub3838/9/ Please check the console output of your code. Sorry :(